# MySQL stored procedures syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am try to execute below code for my stored procedure and it throws error at line number 14. I am unable to locate what is error, help me to resolve.

```
DELIMITER $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SetGems (
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    p_requestid int/* =null */,
    p_akcija int/* =null */)
 BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if p_akcija = 0 then

    declare @v_userId char(36);
    declare @v_vingems int;

    select @v_userId:=r.user_id, @v_vingems := r.value from Requests r
    where r.Id=p_requestid; 

    update Users 
    set balance=balance+@v_vingems
    where id=v_userId;

    else

    declare @v_userrId longtext;
    declare @v_vingemss int;

    select @v_userrId.user_id:=r.user_id, @v_vingemss := r.value from Requests r
    where r.Id=p_requestid;

    update Users 
    set balance=balance-@v_vingems
    where id=v_userrId;
    end if;
 end;  $$    
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What's the structure of the `Requests` table?

Comment: @apokryfos http://prntscr.com/aqxr4o

Comment: Value is decimal and user_id is int, they don't seem to match the data-types of your variables.

Comment: @apokryfos I changed varchar to int and int to decimal and I still get the same error

Comment: Try stripping you example down to its bare minimums first to dismiss any chance that the error is elsewhere. E.g. create a smaller procedure with no arguments and only the 2 declares and the select and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Declare statement are wrong (declare @v_userId char(36),declare @v_vingems int; ..... ). Below is correct code of your procedure:-

```
DELIMITER $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SetGems (
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    p_requestid int/* =null */,
    p_akcija int/* =null */)
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if p_akcija = 0 then
        BEGIN 
            select r.user_id, r.value INTO @v_userId, @v_vingems from Requests r
            where r.Id=p_requestid; 
            update Users 
            set balance=balance+@v_vingems
            where id=v_userId;
        END;
    else
        BEGIN 
            select r.user_id, r.value INTO @v_userId, @v_vingems from Requests r
            where r.Id=p_requestid; 

            update Users 
            set balance=balance-@v_vingems
            where id=v_userrId;
        END;
    end if;
 end $$ 
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a reserved word in your select. "into"

```
select r.user_id,r.value **into** v_userrId, v_vingems from Requests r
where r.Id=p_requestid;
```

Comment: What's wrong with doing `SELECT ... INTO <variables>` ?

Comment: there is still a problem, I found that it should be like @v_userId:=r.user_id but it doesn't work, *sad_face_panda*

Comment: @apokryfos, Did you read the problem and the row error? it is clear that the word "into" in that select is not correct.

Comment: I edited the post, now the code looks like that and I still have the same problem

Comment: @dquinonez That doesn't answer my question as to why valid SQL causes this error.

Comment: is not what is wrong with a SELECT ... INTO, the problem I saw was that Dunster said. I have an error in that specific row, he modified his question now so you cannot confirm what I saw. For that specific error that he said first for me was clear that the error was that "into" in that select. It doesn't made any sense to me in that query. That's all!